# How to keep save textboxes text at form1 in C# when closing this form1 and get back on form1 (reopen it) in MDI container

Tags: c#, mdi

I am using MDI container in my C# program, all works fine but now I am in the problem, that I have a form1 to get info from user in the text boxes then the user clicks a button to go on form2 to select some data from combo boxes and clicks a button on form2 to come back on form1 with the selected data of form2 (selected data from form2 successfully placed in label of form1) all works well here but the previously typed data of user in text boxes are disappeared now (they are blank) so the user have to again retype them then press the SAVE button to save all data in table in database (Sql server ..). Please give me a easy suggestion to solve it.

Comment: You need to share the relevant code which opens Form2 and carries data to Form1. One suggestion is not to close Form1 but hide it when opening Form2 and pass data to it from Form2 while showing it again.

Comment: thanks for a reply, I said in problem that I am using MDI container for all forms. so this is the problem. code to open form2 is: private void AddAlamaatBtn(object sender, EventArgs e)//to go Symptom screen
        {
            Symptoms Sym = new Symptoms();
            MainClass.ShowWindow(Sym, this, MDI.ActiveForm);
        }

Comment: You need to share the code in the question itself. Code in comments in not readable. Also the amount of code you shared does not explain the issue you are facing. `AddAlamaatBtn` is part of which class, Form1, Form2 or MDIContainer.  Which version of .NET Framework you are using?